# Can I evaluate the sum of all entries above 0 in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I got a pyspark dataframe which looks as follows:

```
df.show()
+-------+---------+
| class | counter |
+-------+---------+
|     1 |       1 |  <---
|     1 |       0 |
|     1 |       1 |
|     1 |       2 |  <---
|     1 |       0 |
|     1 |       2 |
|     1 |       4 |
+-------+---------+
|     2 |       1 |
|     2 |       2 |
|     2 |       3 |  <---
|     2 |       0 |
|     2 |       1 |
|     2 |       5 |
|     2 |      10 |
+-------+---------+
```

I would like now to get the sum of all the numbers that have a zero below them. The result in the example would be `1+2=3` for class 1 and `3`for class 2.

I started like this:

```py
w1 = Window().partitionBy().orderBy("class")

res = df.withColumn(
    "lagged", f.coalesce(f.lag(f.col("COUNTER"), 1).over(w1), f.col("counter"))
)
```

This would give me a new column with the shifted counter value. But I would like to filter now by only the rows that have a zero and sum these values up to get one single value per class.

Can you help me achieve what I want?

Comment: Impossible to do without a column to maintain the order. `class` is your partition column, not the ordering column. You need another column to perform this task otherwise, it would be absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a column to maintain the order, the computation is absurd because the order is not guaranteed.

Let's assume you have a column to maintain the order :

```py
df.show()
+--------+-----+-------+                                                        
|ordering|class|counter|
+--------+-----+-------+
|       1|    1|      1|
|       2|    1|      0|
|       3|    1|      1|
|       4|    1|      2|
|       5|    1|      0|
|       6|    1|      2|
|       7|    1|      4|
|       1|    2|      1|
|       2|    2|      2|
|       3|    2|      3|
|       4|    2|      0|
|       5|    2|      1|
|       6|    2|      5|
|       7|    2|     10|
+--------+-----+-------+
```

Then, you just need to compute the lag value, filter the lines with 0 and sum the lagged value.

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("class").orderBy("ordering")

df.withColumn("lagged", F.lag(F.col("COUNTER")).over(w)).where("counter = 0").groupBy(
    "class"
).sum("lagged").show()

+-----+-----------+                                                             
|class|sum(lagged)|
+-----+-----------+
|    1|          3|
|    2|          3|
+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Yes sure, I need an ordering column. I accidentally removed it when creating a minimal example.